# Is explicitly calling a class' cast operator method better than casting?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

If a class offers a method `operator wchar_t*` and I am using an instance of this class in a situation the compiler cannot deduce the casting automatically, is it considered bad to invoke the cast operator method explicitly instead of actually performing the cast?

e.g:

`x.doStuff(o.operator wchar_t*())`

Vs

`x.doStuff(static_cast<wchar_t*>(o))`

Is the first option bad/wrong, or is calling an operator method quite acceptable?

Comment: I would use the word "surprising", and as a result not preferable.

Comment: Do you explicitly call `operator=` for assignment?

Comment: @Damon that's hardly comparable. Casting is by its very nature a little kludgy.

Comment: @John: Well yes, but if you write something like `static_cast<blah>(...)` then everybody immediately understands the intent. If you write something like `foo = 5;` everybody understands as well. If you write `foo.some_operator(...)`, then at least 50% of your readers will have a "huh, wait a second, what?" moment.

Answer (score 2):

At least it's unusual ... especially since the second construction is very idiomatic. Even using the normal cast operator should be better.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use for sure the C++ standard functions.
They're safer and some of them, like static_cast or dynamic_cast allow to test if the cast succeded.

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest advantage of `static_cast< T >( x )` over the C-style `(T)x` is that it is *grepable*. You can *search* for locations in the code where `static_cast`s are done, *and* it carries the information that indeed a **static** cast is intended (as opposed to a dynamic cast, a const cast, or a reinterpret cast).

All these advantages it also has over calling the cast operator explicitly.

Comment: You can search for ".operator" too but it's still a fair point.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if static_cast does what you want, then you should prefer to use it. If it does not, then it should be acceptable to use the explicit cast operator. I would suggest to comment the case.